# Cannot get my gpu and or driver to run on Pop OS 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu, hp

Hello newish to linux and this site.

I have scoured the internet in search for an answer but I have come up empty handed and at a total loss your help is much appreciated thank you. My computer is and old HP XW6400 workstation with a gtx1050ti with Pop OS 20.04 nvidia iso. nvidia driver 440 installed. But it only runs on integrated graphics. I cannot get the system to run on the dedicated graphics card,Also a funny thing is I have my hdmi cable to a tv coming from the dedicated gpu which does display everything but without sound but it says its running on integrated graphics? I do not have a secure boot option in my bios, sorry Im a total greenhorn when it comes to linux.

Also the nvidia x server settings app opens to a blank screen. I have installed the latest Pop OS 20.04 Nvidia iso. 440 driver, after trying the 20.10 Nvidia iso. 455 driver version with the same issues.

`dwill63@pop-os:~$ nvidia-settings`

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:295163): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 05:34:31.840: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:295163): WARNING **: 05:34:31.845: PRIME: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or directory)
** Message: 05:34:31.845: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I have issues where my gpu driver is not running or being seen I get multiple errors trying to run different commands in the CLI like

`dwill63@pop-os:~$ nvidia-smi`

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

`dwill63@pop-os:~$ sudo system76-power graphics nvidia`

```
setting graphics to nvidia
daemon returned an error message: "does not have switchable graphics"
```

It shows the nvidia-driver-440

`dwill63@pop-os:~$ modinfo nvidia`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-7642-generic/kernel/drivers/char/drm/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        440.100
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     79812FEC91C545B3F516DF2
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        ipmi_msghandler
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia
vermagic:       5.4.0-7642-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           NvSwitchRegDwords:NvSwitch regkey (charp)
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler:int
parm:           NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers:int
parm:           NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableUserNUMAManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_KMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_VMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_IgnoreMMIOCheck:int
parm:           NVreg_NvLinkDisable:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterPCIDriver:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_GpuBlacklist:charp
parm:           NVreg_TemporaryFilePath:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp
```

`dwill63@pop-os:~$ inxi -GS`

```
System:
  Host: pop-os Kernel: 5.4.0-7642-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: fbdev,nouveau 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 640x480~73Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 128 bits) 
  v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8
```

`dwill63@pop-os:~$ sudo gpu-manager`

```
[sudo] password for dwill63: 
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.4.0-7642-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.4.0-7642-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1c82
BusID "PCI:64@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:40:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```

Sorry for all the command stuff just trying to get as much info out as i can.Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hi! The first thing you should run is `lsmod`. This will list all of the kernel modules (aka drivers) that are currently loaded. If that list doesn't have `nvidia`, then there is a problem with your driver installation.